# Connecting RemoteApp to Existing Session

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, remoteapp

Due to limitations of an app I've got to run, I've got a server auto logging in on boot with the app on auto start. Remote desktop at my leisure to check on its status, etc.

Gross, but it works.

Now I've tried out RemoteApp which seems to work ok (ie. remotes the notification icon, balloons...) except for the fact that it creates a new session (and therefore instance of my app) - this confuses the heck out of app and it means that if I was using 'full' remote desktop I lose all my state.

["Restrict each user to a single session" doesn't work.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302883)

IIRC "Windows XP Mode" uses RemoteApp and it doesn't seem to have any trouble switching between modes.

So how can I connect to a running app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RemoteApp and standard Remote Desktop are seen as two different session type and so you can't just "merge" them. They don't go through the same steps, as explorer.exe is not started in remote App.